# Striped divider CSS

Tags: css

I've a little CSS problem,

I tried to do this :

[image: STRIPED DIVIDER]

And I couldn't find a way to do it properly (look kinda the same),
I tried things like background-linear-gradient, didn't have what I wanted :/

Is this even possible to do that with CSS ? Thanks for your help :D

Théo

Comment: cut a little image and repeat it with background-repeat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`repeating-linear-gradient`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/repeating-linear-gradient):

```css
.divider {
  height:20px;
  background:repeating-linear-gradient(-45deg,#fff 0px,#fff 4px,#000 4px,#000 8px);
}
```

```html
<div class="divider">

</div>
```

Comment: That worked like a charm, didn't knew that exists, thanks for your help!